# Python Regex text and time same line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to grab a NHL schedule, its format is:

```
    tabindex="1" >Game: Wild at Blackhawks 8:00PM ET</a>
```

I can grab it like:

```
    tabindex="1" >Game: (.)(.*?) at (.)(.*?)</a>
```

That Grabs the first letter of the team names then the rest (coloring purposes) plus the start time.

I have tried variations of the following from posts I've found in here:

```
    (?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?(.+?)$ (ET|PT)
```

However I would like to grab the Time, AM/PM, and ET separately for coloring as well.  What stumps me is to figure out how to grab Text and Date following eachother in a line.  Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below to grab Time, AM/PM, and ET or PT-

```
>>>re.findall(r'([\d:]*)([A-Z]+)\s*([A-Z]+)(?=</a>)','tabindex="1" >Game: Wild at Blackhawks 8:00PM ET</a>')
>>>[('8:00', 'PM', 'ET')]
```

See [<kbd>LIVEDEMO</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/eD9hX6/3)

Comment: That is perfect SIslam Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> s = 'tabindex="1" >Game: Wild at Blackhawks 8:00PM ET</a>'
>>> m = re.search(r'tabindex="1" >Game: (\w)(\w*?) at (\w)(\w*?) (\d+:\d\d)(\w\w) (\w\w)</a>', s)
>>> m.groups(0)
('W', 'ild', 'B', 'lackhawks', '8:00', 'PM', 'ET')
```

Comment: This one did not work for me.  Most likely an error on my end tho, I am pretty bad at regex.